# Bind existing C variable to Lua using Lua C API

Tags: c++, binding, lua

Few years ago I used luabind for binding C++ objects to Lua and vice versa. There was a way to bind existing (allocated through new operator in C++ code) object to Lua and using it in a script like:

```
binded_object.property = new_value
```

Now I am working on a new project where I would like to add some scripting. For the sake of simplicity no boost or any heavy templates are desired. So my question is how to do it using only Lua C Api?

Unfortunately, all examples I encountered show how to bind custom C++ type to Lua and then create a new object of that type in the script and finally return the object to C++.

Comment: *For the sake of simplicity no boost or any heavy templates are desired.* Boost was made to simplify things, y'know? And my Lua API wrapper with something what you would call "heavy templates" fits in about 500 LoC.

Comment: I do realise it was made to simplify things. Also I like boost but not for this particular project. The goal is not to use any dependencies but Lua itself.

Comment: Is standard library also a dependency for you?

Comment: Does it really matter? The question is how to do it using Lua C Api without boost nor templates.

Comment: I assume then you aren't going to use standard library containers (like `vector`, `set` etc.) too, because they use templates? I could probably answer your question, but requirements are unclear.

Comment: I am going to use STL. May I ask for your help with this topic?

Comment: Isn't STL library (which is different from C++ Standard Library) based on templates, which you don't want to use?

Comment: STL comes out of the box. I simply do not want boost.

Comment: Have fun reinventing the wheel, then.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely will.

Answer (score 1):

You want [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).  No Boost, no heavy templates, just all the bindings you could ever want, autogenerated for your convenience.

Now, your question isn't totally clear: by "only Lua C Api", you might mean "making all the Lua C API calls manually in code I write myself".  If that's what you mean, take it from someone who's been there: *you don't actually want to do that*.  It's difficult and unrewarding, and you get nothing whatsoever in exchange.  Use SWIG.  If you want, you can manually edit the bindings it generates, but use SWIG.